# Mock a class imported in a different module

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock

Let's say I have those modules:

`a.py`

```py
class C:
    ...
```

`b.py`

```py
from a import C
...
def foo():
   c = C()
   ...
...
```

now I want to write a test for module `b`

`test_b.py`

```py
import unittest
import mockito

from b import foo


class TestB(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_foo():
      actual = foo()
      ...
```

I want "control" the behavior of `foo()` during the test, and I want to replace, during the `test_foo()` run, that when `C()` is created, inside `foo()`, it's not the "real" `C` class, but a mocked one, with a custom behavior
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `unittest.mock.patch`:

```py
import unittest.mock

from a import C
from b import foo

class MockC:
    ...

class TestB(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_foo():
        with unittest.mock.patch('a.C', new=MockC):
            actual = foo() # inside foo C will be the MockC class
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to `import b` into your `test_b.py`, and then assign to `b.C` your mocked class, like this:

```py
import unittest

import b

class TestB(unittest.TestCase):
    class MockC:
        def talk(self):
            return 'Mocked C'

    def test_foo(self):
        b.C = self.MockC
        talk = b.foo()  # returns C().talk()
        assert talk == 'Mocked C'  # ok
```